# python-win32 Python Exe is not running on Windows 2003

Tags: python

I have written the Python script that used to get the CPU usage, RAM, and
Disk usage from the Windows server.

Then I converted the script to .exe through to execute on server.

The .exe is running fine on windows 2008 sever but it is giving an error
while executing on windows 2003. Below is the error:

```
C:\dist>Monitor_server.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `Monitor_server.py`, line 9, in <module>
  File `psutil\__init__.pyo`, line 85, in <module>
  File `psutil\_psmswindows.pyo`, line 15, in <module>
  File `_psutil_mswindows.pyo`, line 12, in <module>
  File `_psutil_mswindows.pyo`, line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Here is my Python script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import string
import smtplib,datetime
import time
import os,shutil
import codecs
import psutil
import re
import gc,sys
import objgraph

def mem(each_pro):
        rss,vms = each_pro.get_memory_info()
        if rss > 100 * 1024 * 1024:
            each_pro.kill()
            os.startfile("D:\Interface.exe")
        else:
            return

#####  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True: 
        all_pro = psutil.get_process_list()
        for each_pro in all_pro:
            pro_n = re.search(r'\'.+\..+\'',str(each_pro))  
            if pro_n:
                    p_ln = pro_n.group()
                    p_ln = p_ln[1:-1]
                    if p_ln.lower() == "Interface.exe":
                        mem(each_pro)
                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                pass
        time.sleep(500)
```

Comment: Could you show the script?

Comment: Could you format the script?

Comment: This is a thing that happens -- different platforms need different DLLs, but which DLLs to include are determined by (and thus dependent on) the build system; DLLs which would be needed on a different version of Windows but aren't needed on the build system itself aren't included. There isn't an easy fix, and the behavior isn't tied to your code as much as it is to its dependency chain.

Comment: Comparing the output of `python -m py2exe.mf -d yourscript.py` on the two platforms is a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Also, the script itself is much less interesting/useful/informative than the `setup.py` you use with it.

Answer (score 0):

[The Windows C module used by psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/_psutil_windows.c) includes several preprocessor conditionals looking at the version of Windows it's being compiled on, making it fairly specific to that release.

You'll need to build a package for different major versions.

Specifically:

- At WIN32_WINNT 0x0501 (XP+SP2), process memory counters are used.
- At WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 (Vista), NtQueryInformationProcess is used.
- When _WIN64 is set for a natively 64-bit build, the datatypes involve differ (long longs, rather than longs).

---

Now, let's look at how that [compares against the versions of Windows you're using here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745(v=vs.85).aspx):

- Windows Server 2003 uses WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
- Windows Server 2008 uses WIN32_WINNT 0x0600 (same as Vista)

...so, there's your answer: The interface used on Windows Server 2008 and Vista isn't available on 2003. (You may be able to compile on 2003 and use the resulting binary on 2008, but this will lose the advantages of the newer interface).